# How do I display Promise rejection data in Ember's error template?

Tags: ember.js, promise

I want to display information about the rejected model promise in my Ember error templates. The [Ember error routing documentation says](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/):

> The "reason" for the error (i.e. the exception thrown or the promise reject value) will be passed to that error state as its model.

So here is some code trying to test this, with an application route that rejects a promise with an error message, and an error route and template that tries to display it:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('fail');
});

App.FailRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      reject('This is an error message');
    });
  }
});

App.ErrorRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);

    // This always alerts with "Error model is null", when I expect
    // "Error model is This is an error message" instead
    alert('Error model is ' + model);
  }
})
```

And the error template:

```
  <h2>An error happened</h2>

  {{#if model}}
  Message: {{model}}
  {{else}}
  But no message was given
  {{/if}}
```

When I try to do this, my error route (and therefore template) never receives the rejection object as its model.

[Here is a JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cugobo/4/edit) with the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of annoying, but the `reason` you pass to `reject` has to be an object for it to be properly passed to the error state as its model.

Here's all you need:

```
App.FailRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((_, reject) => {
            reject({error: 'This is an error message'});
        });
    }
});
```

And then for your error template you just reference `{{model.error}}`.

That worked for me, whereas just using a string as the `reason` didn't...

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug, but at least in the case of rejection through a promise - here is what worked for me.

```
App.FailRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      reject('This is an error message');
    });
  },

  actions: {
    error: function(error, transition) {
      this.transitionTo('error', error);
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

Then, in the error template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="error">
  {{link-to 'Back' 'index'}}

  <h2>An error happened</h2>

  {{#if model}}
    Message: {{model.error}}
  {{else}}
    But no message was given
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

Your updated (working) JSBIN [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/suxeju/1/edit?html,js,console,output)